# Trimming the beginning and end of string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, split, trim

I have quite a long string that I want to trim the beginning and ending of. See a random example below:

> { "topic": "birds", "body":"cool bird", "attachment1":"bird1", "attachment2":"anotherbird" }

My desired output:

> "attachment1":"bird1", "attachment2":"anotherbird"

I want to keep the attachments so I would have to trim everything up to the first attachment "attachment1" and get rid of the '}' as well as the extra space.

FYI- I am using SQL Server. Any feedback or suggestions would be super helpful! Thank you. :)

EDIT: If '"attachment1":' cannot be found in the string, I'd like the value to return NULL instead of returning the original string. How would I modify the answer to incorporate this rule?

Comment: Why not instead treat it like what it is, JSON, and then get the values out like that instead?

Comment: I'll have to look into JSONs. Thank you for the suggestion! @Larnu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
select replace(stuff(str, 1, charindex('"attachment1":', str), ''), ' }', '')
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1520b6dedd822ef3be4c646253a1a147) is a db<>fiddle.

EDIT:

Probably the simplest solution to handle a missing `"attachment"` is to use `case`:

```
select (case when str like '%"attachment1"%' 
             then replace(stuff(str, 1, charindex('"attachment1":', str), ''), ' }', '')
        end)
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi again, I had a question about this. If '"attachment1":' cannot be found in the string, I'd like the value to return NULL instead of returning the original string. How would I modify your code to incorporate this rule? @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 1):

By using JSON API in SQL Server 2016 and later.

The `STRING_AGG()` function is available in SQL Server 2017 onwards.

The beauty of this method is that "attachment%" key/value pairs could be in any location.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @JSON NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'{ "topic": "birds", "body":"cool bird", "attachment1":"bird1", "attachment2":"anotherbird" }';

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT [key], [value]
    FROM OPENJSON(@JSON)
)
SELECT STRING_AGG(FORMATMESSAGE('"%s":"%s"', [key], [value]), ',') AS Result
FROM rs
WHERE rs.[key] LIKE 'attachment%';
```

**Output**

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
|                       Result                       |
+----------------------------------------------------+
| "attachment1":"bird1","attachment2":"anotherbird"  |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: `FORMATMESSAGE`?? Why wouldn't you just `CONCAT('"', [key], '":"', [value], '"')`

Comment: @Charlieface, it is more simple, and resembles `string.format()` .Net function.